# Stapling Attached Documents, UK Visa

Tags: visas, uk, paperwork

Some of my documents for the UK Visa consist of 2 or 3 pages so I stapled them. But I've read online that when you submit your papers on your appointment day, your documents should not be stapled, is that true?

Comment: There is nothing in the U.K. Immigration Rules or Visit Guide about not stapling papers. If you’ve heard this it may just be the preference of the embassy or visa processing centre where you’re submitting your application.

Answer (score 4):

Don’t staple sets of different documents into one big pile but if the pages make up one single document it’s perfectly normal to have them stapled.

You don’t want to carry a 50 page bank statement as 50 lose pages of supporting documents. That’s a single document and it does need a staple/clip.

Comment: The reason against stapling is in the processing center, where the documents get scanned. Removing staples is just manual labor by the scanner operator.